# A Lower Bound for Estimating a Bernoulli Mean

Tags: mathematical-statistics, bernoulli-distribution, statistical-learning, bounds

I'm trying to understand this paper:
http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/hanneke10a/hanneke10a.pdf

However, I get stuck at Lemma 1, which I will copy here. This lemma is about estimating the mean of a Bernoulli random variable by some estimator $\hat{p}_n$ using $n$ samples. The paper says this is a well-known result however I'm not familiar with it.

> **Lemma 1.** For $0 ≤ a < b ≤ 1$, there exists a constant $c_{a,b} > 0$
>   such that, for any $n ∈ N$, for any estimator $\hat{p}_n : \{0, 1\}^n
>  \to [0, 1]$, there exists a value $p ∈ [a,b]$ such that, if $B_1,B_2,...
>  ,B_n$ are independent $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$ random variables, then
>   $${\mathbb{E}}[(\hat{p}(B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n) − p)^2] > c_{a,b}/n.$$

From the text I understand $c_{a,b}$ does not depend on $n$.

I'm trying to figure out where this lemma comes from, or at least what the conditions are on the estimator $\hat{p}_n$. It is too bad the paper does not refer to any sources and does not give any conditions on the estimator. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think this question can be solved using the following lecture: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture8.pdf